# Theme for OutlinedBox.TextInputLayout not Working

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

Hey I am trying to create a dropdown box with the OutlinedBox theme but the theme is not working.

this is my xml code -

```
        android:id="@+id/add_transaction_category_parent"
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_transaction_date_parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/add_transaction_category"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:hint="category"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and this is the theme I have defined for the TextInputLayout

```
    <style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">1dp</item>

    </style>
```

this is the output UI
[Output UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zxmb.png)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance"
        app:boxStrokeColor="#fff">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textLogin_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

create  style.xml

```
    <style name="TextInputLayoutAppearance" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```